# Combine several row into one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have several record like this. "Count_no" means the primary key, and "override" was the indicator that what row should be override / overwritten.

> [image: Sample record]

For example :
79th Record / row, it must / will be overwritten with the 83th row. (not overwritten by 80th, 81th, or 82th row)

I want the result query like this :

```
Count_no  |  Desc                    |  Desc2                |  Amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
79        |  Revenue from Order #23  |  Change Item : .....  |  0.0000
```

is it possible or not?

Comment: Have you looked into [`GROUP BY` and it's modifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) ?

Comment: If I use rollup function it will only make a sum.. but I need an overwrite act not a sum..

Comment: I know, the point was to show you about the `GROUP BY` function and the fact that there are modifiers - on the right of that page is another link with more information, covering `HAVING` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
  T1.Count_no
  T1.Desc
  IFNULL(T2.Desc2,T1.Desc2) as Desc2
  T1.Amount
FROM T T1
LEFT JOIN T T2 on T1.Count_no=T2.override
```